# Facebook SSO implementation in storyboard- blank screen after login

Tags: ios, facebook, storyboard

I am trying to implement Facebook SSO in storyboard (Xcode 4.2) and the AUTH dialog goes perfectly until the login is completed. At that point Facebook appears to return to my app but what actually shows up is a white screen which, despite my best efforts, I cannot dismiss. From searching on Stack Overflow this seems like an infrequent problem encountered on other platforms as well but I didn't find any answers for IOS.

My best guess is that this is caused by some misstep of mine in implementing the facebook tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ in storyboard, not XIB. Unfortunately the only facebook example projects I've found use Xib's. But honestly I don't really understand the issue or the AUTH dialog that well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking check out the latest Facebook SDK 3.1 and sample that uses story boards: https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-social-cafe

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to an issue I had . . . have you checked to make sure your segue goes to the correct viewController?

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue. Thanks for your help though.